# Why does Charles ignore Magneto's actions?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

Minor spoilers in the question - you might want to skip this if you haven't seen the movie.

In the climax of X-Man: Apocalypse, Magneto is wreaking havoc (pun intended) on the Earth.  Magneto is causing magnetic destruction around the Earth, destroying bridges, sending cars flying, boats capsizing, etc, etc.  These actions must have caused the death of thousands, if not tens of thousands of lives, or even more.

In X-Men: Days of Future past, he hated Eric for (supposedly) killing one man, President Kennedy.  While I can understand Charles *might* forgive the murders of the men who were present at his wife and daughter's death and at the factory (although Eric didn't kill the men, even though he intended to), why is Charles so accepting of Eric's genocide at the end of Apocalypse?

Comment: Because they are BFFs

Comment: Remember that part when he and the new X-Men go out to prevent Apocalpyse and Eric from committing genocide? They're not exactly simply accepting it.

Answer (score 5):

Charles did not exactly ignore Eric. Spoilers bigger than those in the question below.

When Charles sought out Eric telepathically, he saw into his mind and felt the grief and pain within him. I would believe that Charles tolerated the fact that Eric did murder those men even if he did not approve of it - after all, he knew Eric was only human and what's done cannot be undone. That matter is not something Charles intended to debate and dwell on any further, not when he could also sense how Eric's misery and despair is starting to set him back on the path he once walked as Magneto. Charles did not ignore Eric here, he tried to dissuade him but to no avail.

The next time Charles was able to interact with Eric, he had been captured by Apocalypse. Unable to deal with Apocalypse at the moment, Charles turned to Eric and tried to dissuade him from this path again, still without success. Subsequently, they were separated, with Apocalypse carrying Charles away while Magneto was set upon his task to begin tearing the world asunder.

By the time Charles was freed (but not before he lost his hair over the ongoing crisis), he could no longer afford to deal with Eric. He realised by now that defeating Apocalypse must take absolute priority over all else - the head of the snake must be cut off first and foremost. Only after can he afford to turn and deal with Magneto, if the latter still persisted in his course to destroy all muggle-kind by that point in time.

Comment: no disrespect but, "mugglekind"? different universe!

Comment: @krishna Find a better term to describe humans who aren't special.

Comment: HUMANS. the rest are mutants. O_o

Comment: @krishna Mutants are humans too! #mutantlivesmatter